# Doctrine 2 DQL Query to return a filtered association

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have an entity Party with an one-to-many bi-directional association to PartyContact.  I am trying to write a DQL statement to return a filtered PartyContact collection while using object hydration.  I can return the desired result using array hydration but when I attempt to return a pure object hydration I receive the total collection.

There are a total of 5 PartyContact instances association with a Party(with an id of 1), and 3 of the 5 PartyContact instances associated with this Party instance have a property named type with a value of `PartyContact::TYPE_HOME;`  So I should be able to return a Party instance with filtered collection of 3 PartyContact instances.

In the past I have used event listeners, closures, and or filter iterators to handle filtering of collections on entities. Performance wise this seems like a bit much. I am aware of the new Filters with Doctrine 2.2 but would like to be able to handle this in DQL in my repositories.

FYI I am using 2.2.0-BETA2 (note: just checked this and I know that there has been a release of 2.2.2 so I will try that now)

I have the following dql:

```php
$query = $this->_em->createQuery("SELECT p, c FROM Test\Party p LEFT JOIN p.contactMechanisms c WITH c.type = :type WHERE p.id = :id");
$query->setParameter('type', PartyContact::TYPE_HOME);
$query->setParameter('id', 1);
$query->setFetchMode("Test\Party", "contactMechanisms", "EAGER");
$results = $query->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
$party = $results[0];
```

My results are as follows:

- When using Query::getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY):

```php
count($party['contactMechanisms']) = 3
```

- When using Query::getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY):

```php
$party->getContactMechanisms()->count() = 5
```

Comment: Can you try the query without $query->setFetchMode("Test\Party", "contactMechanisms", "EAGER");

Comment: Turns out I had to clear my cache, all works as expected now.

Comment: Ah I see, try sticking with \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache in development ;)